# How do I remove a repository of yum

Tags: repository, centos, yum

When I search for a package in yum(centos 6), it tries to search in a repro named 'c6-media'
And it gives a bunch of errors as follows

```
file:///media/CentOS/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] Could not open/read file:///media/CentOS/repodata/repomd.xml
Trying other mirror.
file:///media/cdrecorder/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] Could not open/read file:///media/cdrecorder/repodata/repomd.xml
Trying other mirror.
file:///media/cdrom/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] Could not open/read file:///media/cdrom/repodata/repomd.xml
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: c6-media. Please verify its path and try again
```

Obviously the error seems to say that yum is trying to search 
for the CD/DVD which installed the OS. I do not have it now.
All I want to do now is to delete this repository from yum.
I went to the package manager graphical tool and removed this from the sources.
Seems yum and the graphical tool do not use the same config. This is just my guess.

Comment: Did you run yum update to update the index file with the new set of repos?

Answer (score 31):

All the yum repos located at `/etc/yum.repos.d/`. So, you can remove a repo with:

```
# rm -f /etc/yum.repos.d/c6-media.repo
```

Or temporary disable it with:

```
# yum --disablerepo=c6-media search ...
```

*(Change `enabled=1` to `enabled=0` in `c6-media.repo` for permanent)*

Answer (score 5):

New in 6.0 or 6.1 (can't remember which off hand) is yum-config-manager, which you can use to disable a repo.:

```
yum-config-manager --disable c6-media
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issue and it was cause by enabling media from local device (CD / DVD). It causes yum to lock up and had to kill the process to recover.

edit /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Media.repo

notice the file names in the following section match the error
baseurl=file:///media/CentOS/
        file:///media/cdrom/
        file:///media/cdrecorder/

Simply change enabled=1 to enabled=0 or do as quanta says as well.